# POSH Tools for VS - Cannot debug scripts/modules in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, powershell-5.0

I've got the latest version of POSH Tools for VS installed (3.0.375 at time of writing) in Visual Studio Community 2015.

After creating any PowerShell Script/Module Project, I can't run or debug it in Visual Studio. Running it without a file open just causes the script/module to 'build'.

```
------ Build started: Project: PowerShellModuleProject1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I also get this in the debug pane.

```
C:\PowerShellModuleProject1\PowerShellModuleProject1.psd1

The program 'PowerShellModuleProject1.psd1: PowerShell Script' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Running it with a tab open, just opens that file in the PowerShell ISE. Trying to run the function provided in the project gives me the usual error:

```
Get-Function : The term 'Get-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Function
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Function:String) [], CommandNotFou 
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension has no effect. I still get the same thing.

This is being run on Windows 10 Home, VS Community 2015 (Update 2) with the latest version of POSH Tools for VS from the extensions gallery.

**UPDATE:**
Somehow, plain scripts are working now, however modules are not. I've found this error in the debug output.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE> C:\PowerShellModuleProject1\PowerShellModuleProject1.psm1
[ERROR] Program 'PowerShellModuleProject1.psm1' failed to run: Application not foundAt 
[ERROR] line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + . 'C:\PowerShellModuleProject1\PowerShellModuleProject1.psm1'
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + . 'C:\PowerShellModuleProject1\PowerShellModuleProject1.psm1'
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedEx 
[ERROR]    ception
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't solve the underlying problem, but I created a separate ps1 file named DebugPowerShellModuleProject.ps1 which contains:

```
Remove-Module PowerShellModuleProject
Import-Module PowerShellModuleProject
Get-Function
```

I can then put a breakpoint on the Get-Function function and it gets hit when I start debugging by running or pressing F5 on the DebugPowerShellModuleProject file. Has the added advantage that I can pass in parameters to Get-Function by specifying it right there on the call to the function.